# Fast way to swap bytes in array from big endian to little endian in C#

Tags: c#, endianness

I'm reading from a binary stream which is big-endian. The BitConverter class does this automatically. Unfortunately, the floating point conversion I need is not the same as BitConverter.ToSingle(byte[]) so I have my own routine from a co-worker. But the input byte[] needs to be in little-endian. Does anyone have a fast way to convert endianness of a byte[] array. Sure, I could swap each byte but there has got to be a trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a fast method for changing endianess for singles in a byte array:

```
public static unsafe void SwapSingles(byte[] data) {
  int cnt = data.Length / 4;
  fixed (byte* d = data) {
    byte* p = d;
    while (cnt-- > 0) {
      byte a = *p;
      p++;
      byte b = *p;
      *p = *(p + 1);
      p++;
      *p = b;
      p++;
      *(p - 3) = *p;
      *p = a;
      p++;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Say my input in hex is 62,4d,00,4e then the output I thought should be 49,62,4e,00 but this could be because I am working in 16bit words. SwapSingles returns 4e,00,4d,62 which is not what I need.

Comment: @initialZero: A Single is four bytes. So, is it that you don't have bytes or that they don't represent a Single?

Answer (score 3):

I use LINQ:

```
var bytes = new byte[] {0, 0, 0, 1};
var littleEndianBytes = bytes.Reverse().ToArray();
Single x = BitConverter.ToSingle(littleEndianBytes, 0);
```

You can also `.Skip()` and `.Take()` to your heart's content, or else use an index in the BitConverter methods.

Comment: Note, `Array.Reverse()` is an old way to do it.

Comment: Fast to implement? Maybe. Fast at runtime? Probably not.

Comment: @Pat Array.Reverse modifies the original array, while .Reverse().ToArray() creates a new array. Huge difference. Nothing about an old or new way of doing it.

Comment: @juFo I meant "old" as in, if you are using a .NET prior to LINQ and thus .Reverse().ToArray(). But good idea to clarify for folks the difference.

Answer (score 0):

What does the routine from your co-worker look like? If it accesses the bytes explicitly, you could change the code (or rather, create a separate method for big-endian data) instead of reversing the bytes.

Comment: I need to convert the array beforehand in the message object.

Comment: Jon, doesn't MiscUtil have an EndianBitConverter?

Comment: @LBushkin: It does, and that was my first thought - but it sounds like this is a different problem.

Comment: @initialZero: It's not at all clear what you mean, I'm afraid. If you've got a routine which is expecting little-endian data, why can't you create an alternative version which expects big-endian data?

Comment: Yes, I just found MiscUtil and am looking at the source. Thanks.

Comment: @Jon, it should be in little-endian. I was initially just going to use BitConverter.ToSingle(byte[]) to store the value. But the conversion is wrong. So now I need to convert the endianness of the raw message and pass it through these predefined functions for conversions.